# Montar un sistema de traducción en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Quiero montar un sistema de traducción en SQL de unos recursos

Ahora mismo tengo dos tablas

**routes**
`uid, sku, ...`

**translate**
`uid, title, lang`

El campo `lang` contiene el código de idoma `es_ES, fr_FR, en_EN...`

### Para obtener recursos

Para devolver los recursos de un idioma concreto uso lo siguiente

```
SELECT tb1.uid, tb1.sku, translations.title, translations.lang FROM routes AS tb1
    inner JOIN translations ON (tb1.uid = translations.uid AND translations.lang = "es_ES")
```

Me devuleve todos los recurso con el idioma `es_ES` si le pongo `en_EN` todos los que están traducidos en ingles

### Problema

El problema es que no tengo todos los recursos traducidos y me gustaría implementar que en caso de no existir el recurso traducido devolviese el establecido por defecto en este caso los `lang=es_ES`

¿Cómo sería la petición de SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues el final lo he resuelto gracias a la ayuda de un compañero en un servidor de discord, en comentarios dejaré el enlace

Dejo como lo he conseguido

```sql
SELECT routes.*, COALESCE(t1.title, t2.title) AS title,  COALESCE(t1.description, t2.description) AS description
FROM routes
LEFT JOIN translations AS t1 ON routes.uid = t1.uid AND t1.lang = '<idioma_alternativo>'
LEFT JOIN translations AS t2 ON routes.uid = t2.uid AND t2.lang = 'es_ES';
```

Comment: Aquí la conversación: https://discord.com/channels/729672926432985098/1077250615157207060